# Python plotly: Save graphic as .svg file

Tags: python, plotly, pysimplegui

I have written a rather extensive code that generates graphs based on input values. Originally, I wanted to save the graphics as an html file (which also works). However, I now have a request to save the graphics as an .svg file as well.

Unfortunately I can't manage to implement this. My code always hangs up.

Is there a simple solution to this? Below you will find an excerpt from my code:

```
def save_chart_to_html(fig, filename):
    pio.write_html(fig, file=filename, auto_open=False)

def open_chart_in_browser(filename):
    url = f'file://{os.path.abspath(filename)}'
    webbrowser.open(url, new=1)

...

 while True:
                    event_popup, values_popup = window_popup.read()
                    if event_popup == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
                        break

                    if event_popup == 'open_chart_link3':
                        Sens_Strompreis_Wärmeentstehungskosten(Sens_Input_Daten['min_0'], Sens_Input_Daten['max_0'],Sens_Input_Daten['step_0'],mit_erlöse=False)
                        filename3 = "chart_stromkosten.html"
                        fig_strom = Sens_Strompreis_Wärmeentstehungskosten_Grafik(Sens_Stromkosten_Ergebnisse,mit_erlöse=False)
                        save_chart_to_html(fig_strom, filename3)
                        open_chart_in_browser(filename3)

                        
                    if event_popup == 'open_chart_link3_1':
                        Sens_Strompreis_Wärmeentstehungskosten(Sens_Input_Daten['min_0'], Sens_Input_Daten['max_0'],Sens_Input_Daten['step_0'],mit_erlöse=True)
                        filename3_1 = "chart_stromkosten_mit_Erlöse.html"
                        fig_strom_2 = Sens_Strompreis_Wärmeentstehungskosten_Grafik(Sens_Stromkosten_Ergebnisse,mit_erlöse=True)
                        save_chart_to_html(fig_strom_2, filename3_1)
                        open_chart_in_browser(filename3_1)

...
```

Attention: I use a PySimpleGui interface

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Add Print statements to check where your code hands up.